# Use the Timer c#

Tags: c#

I have a problem with my app, I'm doing a batch file, but when I try call the method, the method enables timer1, but timer1 doesn't work, only it works in the moment when the function is the end, so, I need to see all the process, but only I can see the last one.
The method "segundero" enables the timer1, but it does not manage to enter until the end of the processes.
Could you help me please?

```
Stopwatch oSW = new Stopwatch();    
 void segundero()
     {
        oSW.Start();
        
        timer1.Start();
        timer1.Enabled = true;
        
    }

    void recorrido(int i)
    {
        int num1;
        int num2;
        int res = 0;
        for(int k =i; k<= i+3; k++)
        {
            
            if (k < NuProcesos)
            {
                num1 = ListOp1[k];
                num2 = ListOp2[k];
                if (Oper[k] == "+")
                {
                    res = num1 + num2;
                }
                else if (Oper[k] == "-")
                {
                    res = num1 - num2;
                }
                else if (Oper[k] == "*")
                {
                    res = num1 * num2;
                }
                else if (Oper[k] == "/")
                {
                    res = num1 / num2;
                }
                else if (Oper[k] == "%")
                {
                    res = num1 % num2;
                }
                operacionactual = ListOp1[k].ToString() + Oper[k].ToString() + ListOp2[k] + " = " + res.ToString(); ;
                SegundoTerminar = LisTime[k];
                SegundoTerminar1 = LisTime[k];
                loteproceso.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = NombreP[k];
                loteproceso.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value = operacionactual;
                loteproceso.Rows[0].Cells[2].Value = LisTime[k];
                loteproceso.Rows[0].Cells[3].Value = IDNumero[k];
                segundero();
                
                procesoterminado.Rows.Add(IDNumero[k], operacionactual, nlote);
            }
        }
    }
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, (int)oSW.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        SegundoMenos = SegundoMenos + 1;
        SegundoTerminar = SegundoTerminar - 1;
        loteproceso.Rows[0].Cells[4].Value = SegundoTerminar;
        loteproceso.Rows[0].Cells[5].Value = SegundoMenos;
        if (SegundoTerminar==0) 
        {
            oSW.Reset();
            timer1.Enabled = false;
        }

    }
```

Comment: You are only updating Row 0, is that what you need?

Comment: Yes,  I only  need to rewrite in that row, but all the process in real time.

Comment: seeing it one by one, each process, for example, in the first I have a process with the time of 5 seconds, and in the next, the process has 4 seconds, so, see the first process during 5 seconds, and in the second for 4 seconds.

Comment: I have seen the problem, is that the timer only begin when the principal button ends its process, but I need each process, every call to the function segundero.

Answer (score 0):

have you traied to put += to your timer so in every tick it will enter the event timer1_Tick

Comment: I don't undertand, how is the use for +=?

Comment: seeing it one by one, each process, for example, in the first I have a process with the time of 5 seconds, and in the next, the process has 4 seconds, so, see the first process during 5 seconds, and in the second for 4 seconds.

Comment: I have seen the problem, is that the timer only begin when the principal button ends its process, but I need each process, every call to the function segundero.